# How to crop SVG images in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, crop

I want the sides of this SVG image trimmed:

[image]

I tried opening it with Inkscape, selecting the region I want with the *Rectangle* tool and then *Object → Clip → Set.* But nothing happens.

Comment: Are you selecting [both the mask and the object to clip](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip-Clipping.html)?

Comment: Is the raster with triangle and labels all vector graphic or is it an imported bitmap?

Comment: Draw a rectangle. Then do *Edit > Resize page to selection*. Delete the rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

[image: The rectangle used to clip.]
^ Draw a rectangle around the object and make a copy of it (you'll need it once per path in the SVG). 
[image: The input SVG broken apart]
^ Break apart the input SVG (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to ungroup); this is the only way that this method works.
[image: Selecting each path one-by-one and using Path Intersection to crop them]
^ With each individual path, select it and the rectangle. Execute `Path > Intersection` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. You don't need to do this for a path if that path doesn't go outside of the crop area.
[image: The final result]
^ After doing this for each individual path, you can regroup the SVG if you want.

Hope that helps!